SSH into Lab VM Added Permanently
I made an ssh connection into a vm on the cloud. I'm only practicing labs and don't want to clutter my Ubuntu install. How can I delete this record that's been permantely added to my 24.04 OS?
Warning: Permanently added 'xxx.xxx.xxx' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Linux linuxvm 5.10.0-32-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.223-1 (2024-08-10) x86_64


Are you asking Is it possible to remove a particular host key from SSH's known_hosts file?

This question is similar to: Is it possible to remove a particular host key from SSH's known_hosts file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
